# Warum sagt man "wir treffen uns" oder "ich freue mich", aber nichts nur "wir treffen" oder "ich freue"?

Tags: reflexive

It seems a bit repetitive to refer to oneself again in the same sentence. Is there some grammatical rule behind this for a particular class of verbs?

Comment: If you look for languages that behave "logic", go to programming languages. Natural languages are not made to be "logic", they developed over dozens of centuries and are by nature a collection of oddities.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann that is something my teacher says a lot ! as a programmer I can't help it sometimes and in this case, I wasn't aware of "Reflexiv verben"

Comment: Fun fact: you can say *Ich dusche mich*, but also *Ich dusche*, and there is no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a number of verbs which **require** a reflexive pronoun ("[Reflexivpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexivpronomen)"). They are called "true reflexive verbs" (echte reflexive Verben), and "[sich] freuen" is one of them.
 You can find a list of other verbs here:

https://mein-deutschbuch.de/reflexive-verben.html

Another group of verbs are the "false reflexive verbs" (unechte reflexive Verben).
They can be used reflexive, like in

> "Wir treffen uns morgen".

But they can also be used with accusative:

> "Wir treffen ihn morgen." -> "ihn" is no reflexive pronoun.

To add some fun and confusion:
The verb "treffen" has another meaning: "to hit".
The sentence

> Wir treffen uns morgen.

is fine.

> Ich treffe mich morgen.

means either I shoot myself or I have a multiple personality :-)
However

> Ich treffe mich morgen mit Hans.

is correct. In everyday speech you could even say

> Ich treffe morgen Hans.

It depends on the context which meaning of "treffen" applies, but in most cases Hans should survive ;-)

Comment: To add even more confusion: "jdn treffen" and "sich mit jdm treffen" aren't even fully synonymous. The former can also be used for running into someone, the latter always means meetings on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

German language has two kinds of [reflexive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb): Echte reflexive Verben and unechte reflexive Verben

**Echte reflexive Verben** like *freuen* **always** have a reflexive object (Reflexivpronomen). You can say

> Ich freue mich.
>
> Er freut sich.

but can't say

> Ich freue dich.
>
> Ich freue.

**Unechte reflexive Verben** like treffen or waschen **may** be used reflexive like

> Ich wasche mich.
>
> Wir treffen uns (nächste Woche).

but also with an Akkusativ- or Dativ-Objekt

> Ich wasche die Kleidung.
>
> Ich treffe dich (am Kino).

or simply (in some circumstances)

> Ich wasche.

Answer (score 2):

You might have heard of the differentiation between *transitive* and *intransitive* verbs. In short, a transitive verb requires an object (sometimes multiple objects), an intransitive verb can't be used with a (direct) object.

An example for a transitive verb in English is "to need". You can't just say, "I need", you need to need something ;) On the other hand, "to flow" is intransitive, you can't flow something.

In English, many verbs can be used as transitive or intransitive without change, so the distinction isn't as visible as in other languages. For example, "I open the door" (transitive usage of "to open") and "The door opens" (intransitive usage of "to open") are both correct.

Occasionally, the object that a verb has to have refers back to the subject of the sentence, as in "He hurt himself". Such verbs are called "reflexive verbs". In your examples, "treffen" and "freuen" are such reflexive verbs. In fact, they're typically specified as "sich treffen" and "sich freuen".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that verbs are possibly ambiguous, they **can** be reflexive, but **need not to be**: We could meet the customer, the boss, some of our colleagues or simply each other. Simply to leave out the object for the latter meaning is not idiomatic and seems an unusual shortcut anyway.

(Admittedly this does not really apply to *freuen*, which is impossibly to do with someone else. But it is simply used in the same way.)