# dürfen vs "sich dürfen"?

Tags: verb, grammaticality, reflexive

I am now watching a movie series by DW called Nicos Weg. Here at [1:44:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg5P2w_Ro1c) there is a line:

> Sie darf sich nicht mit mir treffen.

Then I looked it up in the dictionary and found that for most of the examples "dürfen" is used instead of "sich dürfen". Are there any subtle differences between the two? Or they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/50498/3237

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/32962/3237

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding!

The reflexive pronoun **sich** does not belong to the modal verb *dürfen*, but to the reflexive verb **treffen**. Without the modal verb it is something like this:

> - Ich treffe mich mit dir.
> - Du triffst dich mit mir.
> - Er/sie/es **trifft sich** mit mir.
> - Wir treffen uns mit dir.
> - Ihr trefft euch mit mir.
> - Sie **treffen sich** mit mir.

The modal verb *dürfen* just indicates the modality of (not) being allowed or permitted to do something. With the modal verb, the above sentences change as follows:

> - Ich *darf* mich nicht mit dir treffen.
> - Du *darfst* dich nicht mit mir treffen.
> - Er/sie/es *darf* **sich** nicht mit mir **treffen**.
> - Wir *dürfen* uns nicht mit dir treffen.
> - Ihr *dürft* euch nicht mit mir treffen.
> - Sie *dürfen* **sich** nicht mit mir **treffen**.

Comment: Wow! It is so counterintuitive (at least for me) that the "sich" must go with the latter verb and the "nicht" must go with the earlier verb, even when the "sich" is actually placed before the "nicht". German is mesmerising. Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 7):

Dürfen always takes the infinitive.

> Er darf keine Milch trinken.
>   Seit 100 Jahren dürfen deutsche Frauen wählen.

If the infitive is reflexive, like "sich mit jemandem treffen" then it's just the same

> Mein Kind darf sich nicht mit fremden Menschen treffen.